# How to constraint items of different rows with respect to each other?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-constraintlayout

Following is the screenshot which I want to achieve

[image]

Following is my `flutter` code

```
Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                const MyProfileText(
                  text: "Name",
                ),

                const MyProfileText(
                  text: ":",
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 4,
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 30,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: 10,
                    ),
                    child: TextField(
                      cursorColor: black1,
                      style: buildTextStyle(),
                      decoration: buildTextDecoration(),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
```

I have repeated the same row for Email,address etc inside a `column widget`. My output is as follows

[image]

as you can see the textfield is not having equal widths in all the three case as the label name differs in length. I know I can use `SizedBox` with different width between the label and textfield but that does not feel right.Is it possible to constraint or have equal widths of `TextField`, something which we do in Native Android using `Constraint Layout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the left elements inside a `Row` inside a `Flexible` too, this way the root `Row` will have two `Flexible` items with the same width.

Here is a quick example:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Name"),
          Text(":"),
          SizedBox(width: 4),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Flexible(
      child: Container(
        height: 30,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          right: 10,
        ),
        child: TextField(),
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Then, if you want the `Text("Name")` to occupy all available space, wrap it with `Expanded`, like this:

```
Expanded(child: Text("Name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the widgets after ":" text (the ":" text, sizedBox and the flexible widget) in Row. Then you need to wrap the Row you just created and the "Name" text widget with Expanded widget. Code here:

```
Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: const MyProfileText(
                text: "Name",
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  const MyProfileText(
                    text: ":",
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 4,
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 30,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        right: 10,
                      ),
                      child: TextField(
                        cursorColor: black1,
                        style: buildTextStyle(),
                        decoration: buildTextDecoration(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

You can change the flex in the Expanded to change the size of each part.

Answer (score 0):

You need Expanded and flex, you can copy paste full code to check it 
use flex number to adjust size between text and textfield 
code snippet

```
Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Name",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        ":",
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 4,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 30,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: 10,
                    ),
                    child: TextField(),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
```

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Name",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        ":",
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 4,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 30,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: 10,
                    ),
                    child: TextField(),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Email",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        ":",
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 4,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 30,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: 10,
                    ),
                    child: TextField(),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Mobile Number",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        ":",
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 4,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 30,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: 10,
                    ),
                    child: TextField(),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Address",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        ":",
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 4,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 30,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: 10,
                    ),
                    child: TextField(),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```